# MongoDB $lookup returning array with empty

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Product Collection:

```
[
        {
            "isActive": true,
            "_id": "643bbdee68b521035e20c976",
            "name": "lu",
            "price": 123,
            "userId": "643abd0dcce4df3b1a0c8fa7"
        },
         {
            "_id": "643bbdd668b521035e20c972",
            "name": "mu",
            "price": 123,
            "userId": "643abd0dcce4df3b1a0c8fa7",
            "isActive": true,
            "__v": 0
        },
         {
            "isActive": true,
            "_id": "643bbdbc68b521035e20c971",
            "name": "nu",
            "price": 123,
            "userId": "643abd0dcce4df3b1a0c8fa7"
        },
         {
            "_id": "643c2dc126211992b4ee8fd5",
            "name": "pu",
            "price": 123,
            "userId": "643abd0dcce4df3b1a0c8fa7",
            "isActive": true
        }
    ]
```

Subproduct Collection:

```
[
        {
            "_id": "643d7ed82cd5b5fcd7e81e02",
            "name": "kkkk",
            "phoneNum": 9543922499,
            "productID": "643bbdee68b521035e20c976",
            "user": "643abd0dcce4df3b1a0c8fa7",
            "address": {
                "address1": "243, bastin nagarsss",
                "zipCode": 6250185
            }
        }
    ]
```

My aggregare function:

```
aggregateLookup: async () => {
    try {
        let subProduct = await SubProduct.aggregate([
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "Product",
                    localField: "productID",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "product_Details"
                }
            }
        ]);

        return subProduct;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    }
}
```

MY SCHEMA:

```
const subProduct = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true,'Name is Required...']
  },
  phoneNum: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    validate: {
      validator: (value) => {
        return `${value}`.length === 10;
      },
      message: 'Should be 10 digit Number'
    }
  },
  productID: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'Product'
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  address: {
    address1: String,
    zipCode: Number
  }
});
```

In Schema I'm having Product id type as ObjectID. In aggregateLookup function I need to retrieve all data using $lookup I'm having the related product in Product Document But its still returning an empty array.

My output is coming with Product_Details as empty but having data in Product Documents:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "643d7ed82cd5b5fcd7e81e02",
        "name": "kkkk",
        "phoneNum": 9543922499,
        "productID": "643bbdee68b521035e20c976",
        "user": "643abd0dcce4df3b1a0c8fa7",
        "address": {
            "address1": "243, bastin nagarsss",
            "zipCode": 6250185
        },
        "product_Details": []
    }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "643d7ed82cd5b5fcd7e81e02",
        "name": "kkkk",
        "phoneNum": 9543922499,
        "productID": "643bbdee68b521035e20c976",
        "user": "643abd0dcce4df3b1a0c8fa7",
        "address": {
            "address1": "243, bastin nagarsss",
            "zipCode": 6250185
        },
        "product_Details": [
        {
        "isActive": true,
        "_id": "643bbdee68b521035e20c976",
        "name": "lu",
        "price": 123,
        "userId": "643abd0dcce4df3b1a0c8fa7"
        }
        ]
    }
]
```

Please help me What mistake I have made I'm new to mongodb. Thanks in advance...

Comment: One of the common mistakes that causing empty `$lookup` result is mixing `ObjectId` field and `String` field. Make sure you use consistent datatype for lookup fields.

Comment: Thanks for your replay @ray, But I have already mention the type of project id as object in schema. Should I need to do anything else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is surely with the names of collections.

You have used `from:"Product"` instead you need to use the word `products` because you need to provide the exact name of the collection that is formed in the database. because mongoDB automatically assigns plural words to collection names. You can check the collection name by going to mongosh shell and

1. To show list of all database `show dbs`
2. To use a database name `use db_name`
3. To list collections `show collections`

https://mongoplayground.net/p/_bp4jpzUHVg

I have tested it here

Comment: If i need one more level to populate. Can we able to do that example inside Product I'm having userID can we populate user detail inside Product

https://mongoplayground.net/p/UUHJYq7D0p5

Comment: Yeah we can surely do that using another stage in the aggregation pipeline.
I have updated the above query snippet to include the same   
https://mongoplayground.net/p/Xg8SM4bDJzM

Comment: Ya that one i got it. But im asking like can we able to do nested levels 
subProduct-->Product--->user

something like this:

 [ { product_details: [{ user_details: [{ userID: "643abd0dcce4df3b1a0c8fa7" } ] } ] } ]

Comment: @Ajai yes we can do infinite times of lookups and nested lookups

Comment: I have added my code below please check and let me know  what mistake i have done

Answer (score 0):

@Rituparan i checked some document i prepared the below query its not working as expected its comming dirrect child of SubProject with empty array.

```
await SubProduct.aggregate([
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "products",
                        localField: "productID",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "product_Details"
                    }
                },
                {
                    $unwind: "$product_Details"
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "users",
                        localField: "product_Details.userId",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "user_Details"
                    }
                },{
                    $project: {
                        "user_Details.password": 0
                    }
                }
            ]);
```

But my output is

```
[
    {
        "_id": "643d7ed82cd5b5fcd7e81e02",
        "name": "kkkk",
        "phoneNum": 9543922499,
        "productID": "643bbdee68b521035e20c976",
        "user": "643abd0dcce4df3b1a0c8fa7",
        "address": {
            "address1": "243, bastin nagarsss",
            "zipCode": 6250185
        },
        "product_Details": {
            "_id": "643bbdee68b521035e20c976",
            "name": "lu",
            "price": "123",
            "userId": "643abd0dcce4df3b1a0c8fa7"
        },
        "user_Details": []
    }
]
```

I like to have user_Details with values under Product_Details so in query $lookup from "user" i added localField as "Product_Details.userId" still not working. What mistake i done. Plz let me know. I using MongoDB version 5.0.

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "643d7ed82cd5b5fcd7e81e02",
    "address": {
      "address1": "243, bastin nagarsss",
      "zipCode": 6.250185e+06
    },
    "name": "kkkk",
    "phoneNum": 9.543922499e+09,
    "productID": "643bbdee68b521035e20c976",
    "product_Details": [
      {
        "_id": "643bbdee68b521035e20c976",
        "isActive": true,
        "name": "lu",
        "price": 123,
        "userId": "643abd0dcce4df3b1a0c8fa7",
        "user_Details": [
          {
            "_id": "643abd0dcce4df3b1a0c8fa7",
            "age": 23,
            "name": "Rituparna Warwatkar"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "user": "643abd0dcce4df3b1a0c8fa7"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you please post your expected output

Comment: Updated the comment. Please check it

Comment: oh ok ! in as of $lookup, you need to use `as: "product_Details.user_Details"` instead of just `as:"user_details"`. I have shown an example at https://mongoplayground.net/p/wD0Njcx0teP

Comment: Thank you soo much which website we can get more knowledge about mongodb

Comment: Read the documentation, one of the best places... also there's a book https://www.practical-mongodb-aggregations.com/ have a look at it